# Trouble convert .htaccess file to web.config file (microsoft azure) PHP

Tags: php, azure, .htaccess, config

im having some trouble converting my .htaccess code to a web.config format

I tried using this online converted: https://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx

but when i paste the result on the web.config file i get this error on my azure website

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

this error shows on all pages

here is my .htaccess code
`

```
 # Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

Options -MultiViews

php_value upload_max_filesize 10000M
php_value post_max_size 10000M
php_value memory_limit 10000M


# Rewrite for home_1.php
RewriteRule ^home$ home_1.php

# Rewrite for home_1.php
RewriteRule ^feed$ home_1.php

# Rewrite for logout/logout.php
RewriteRule ^logout/logout$ logout/logout.php

# Rewrite for login_1.php
RewriteRule ^login$ login_1.php

# Rewrite for list_product.php
RewriteRule ^listproduct$ list_product.php

# Rewrite for account_settings.php
RewriteRule ^account_settings$ account_settings.php

# Rewrite for includes/functions/cart/remove_item_from_cart.php
RewriteRule ^RemoveItemFromCart$ includes/functions/cart/remove_item_from_cart.php

# Rewrite for includes/functions/cart/move_item_to_wishlist.php
RewriteRule ^MoveItemToWishlist$ includes/functions/cart/move_item_to_wishlist.php



# Rewrite for storesfollowing.php
RewriteRule ^storesfollowing$ storesfollowing.php

# Rewrite for signup.php
RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for cart.php
RewriteRule ^cart$ cart.php [NC,L]

#Rewrite for user_likes.php
RewriteRule ^likes$ user_likes.php


# Rewrite for includes/functions/cart/check_for_coupon.php
RewriteRule ^CheckForCoupon$ includes/functions/cart/check_for_coupon.php

# Rewrite for includes/functions/cart/check_for_coupon.php?rc=1
RewriteRule ^RemoveCoupon$ includes/functions/cart/check_for_coupon.php?rc=1

# Rewrite for checkout/Addresses.php
RewriteRule ^placeorder checkout/Addresses.php

# Rewrite for checkout/EditAddresses.php
RewriteRule ^edit-address checkout/EditAddress.php

# Rewrite for checkout/payments/PayNow.php
RewriteRule ^paynow checkout/payments/PayNow.php

#Rewrite for checkout/OrderCompleted.php
RewriteRule ^OrderCompleted checkout/OrderCompleted.php

# Rewrite for checkout/Payment.php
RewriteRule ^orderpayment checkout/Payment.php

# Rewrite for checkout/ReviewAndPay.php
RewriteRule ^reviewandpay checkout/ReviewAndPay.php

# Rewrite for checkout/payments/paynowform.php
RewriteRule ^paynowform checkout/payments/paynowform.php

# Rewrite for login.php
RewriteRule ^signin$ login_new.php [NC,L]
# Rewrite for seller_login.php
RewriteRule ^sellerlogin$ seller_login.php [NC,L]
# Rewrite for seller_registration.php
RewriteRule ^sellerregistration$ seller_registration.php [NC,L]
# Rewrite for seller_registration_landing.php
RewriteRule ^sellerregistrationabout$ seller_registration_landing.php [NC,L]
# Rewrite for seller_forgot_password.php
RewriteRule ^sellerforgotpassword$ seller_forgot_password.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for staffadmin.php
RewriteRule ^staffadmin$ staffadmin.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for admin_accounts.php
RewriteRule ^adminaccounts$ admin_accounts.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for wishlist.php
RewriteRule ^wishlist$ wishlist.php [NC,L]



# Rewrite for currency_landing.php
RewriteRule ^landing$ currency_landing.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for currency_landing.php
#RewriteRule ^plans$ signup/company_information.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for order_activity.php
RewriteRule ^order-activity$ order_activity.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for notiifcations.php
RewriteRule ^news$ notifications.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for zabeing_wallet.php
RewriteRule ^wallet$ zabeing_wallet.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for wallet_transactions.php
RewriteRule ^transactions$ wallet_transactions.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for withdraws.php
RewriteRule ^withdraws$ withdraws.php [NC,L]
```

`

my web.config

```
<rule name="rule 1e">
<match url="^home$"  />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/home_1.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 2e">
    <match url="^feed$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/home_1.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 3e">
    <match url="^logout/logout$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/logout/logout.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 4e">
    <match url="^login$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/login_1.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 5e">
    <match url="^listproduct$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/list_product.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 6e">
    <match url="^account_settings$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/account_settings.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 7e">
    <match url="^RemoveItemFromCart$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/includes/functions/cart/remove_item_from_cart.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 8e">
    <match url="^MoveItemToWishlist$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/includes/functions/cart/move_item_to_wishlist.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 9e">
    <match url="^storesfollowing$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/storesfollowing.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 10e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^signup$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/signup.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 11e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^cart$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/cart.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 12e">
    <match url="^likes$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/user_likes.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 13e">
    <match url="^CheckForCoupon$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/includes/functions/cart/check_for_coupon.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 14e">
    <match url="^RemoveCoupon$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/includes/functions/cart/check_for_coupon.php?rc=1"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 15e">
    <match url="^placeorder"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/Addresses.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 16e">
    <match url="^edit-address"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/EditAddress.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 17e">
    <match url="^paynow"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/payments/PayNow.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 18e">
    <match url="^OrderCompleted"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/OrderCompleted.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 19e">
    <match url="^orderpayment"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/Payment.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 20e">
    <match url="^reviewandpay"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/ReviewAndPay.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 21e">
    <match url="^paynowform"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/checkout/payments/paynowform.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 22e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^signin$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/login_new.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 23e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^sellerlogin$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/seller_login.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 24e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^sellerregistration$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/seller_registration.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 25e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^sellerregistrationabout$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/seller_registration_landing.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 26e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^sellerforgotpassword$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/seller_forgot_password.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 27e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^staffadmin$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/staffadmin.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 28e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^adminaccounts$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin_accounts.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 29e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^wishlist$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/wishlist.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 30e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^landing$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/currency_landing.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 31e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^order-activity$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/order_activity.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 32e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^news$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/notifications.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 33e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^wallet$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/zabeing_wallet.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 34e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^transactions$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/wallet_transactions.php"  />
</rule>
<rule name="rule 35e" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^withdraws$"  ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/withdraws.php"  />
</rule>
```

I am using a mac so I don't have access to IIS

All answers will very much appreciated

Thanks

Arnav

Comment: Check the troubleshooting section of the Azure docs. There are settings in the portal to increase error reporting. You can access the error logs either via the portal or via FTP. These will include a more meaningful error message. You should post your web.config file as well. Additionally Azure supports hosting on Linux as well. So you can consider running your app on a Linux App Service instead.

Comment: What does the converted config file look like? P.S. 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: @ADyson I've updated my question and added my web.config there 
also where can I see the error logs

Comment: The first comment already gave you advice on finding the error logs

Comment: Sorry my bad just saw it thank @ADyson